# How to replace string in perl with mutiple value

Tags: string, perl, replace, str-replace

Suppose I have a string, and an array as follow:

```
my $str = "currentStringwithKey<i>";
my @arr = ("1", "2");
```

So, is there any better way to quickly replace the string with every value in the array, rather than using for loop, and put the output of each replacement into new array.

My expect output was:

```
my @outputArray = ("currentStringwithKey1", "currentStringwithKey2");
```

Comment: did you mean `my $str[i] = "currentstring";`?

Comment: If you can set the string marker yourself, then you can use sprintf: `my $str = "currentString%s"; my @output = map { sprintf $str, $_ } @arr`.

Comment: @TLP thank you! I am using <i> just for the meaning of a character need to be replace!

Comment: @PatoSáinz i mean the input is just string with some characters that i want to replace by different values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without using for loop use [map](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) for to do it

> /r is the non-destructive modifier used to **Return substitution and leave the original string untouched**

```
my $str = "currentStringwithKey<i>";
my @arr = ("1", "2");                 
my  @output = map{ $str=~s/<i>/$_/rg } @arr;  
#$str not to be changed because of the r modifier
print @output;
```

Then the `@output` array contain like this

```
$output[0] = "currentStringwithKey1",
$output[1] = "currentStringwithKey2"
```

Comment: That will produce `{"currentStringwithKey<i>1", "currentStringwithKey<i>2"}`, not quite what was asked for.  The OP wants to _replace_ the text `<i>` with the number.

Comment: After your edit it does.  But what if the `<i>` was not at the end?  The value of `$str` is a _template_ and the `<i>` is a placeholder.

Comment: Thank @mkHun, that is what i am looking for

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you want.  This approach will replace `<i>` with the the substitution text regardless of where the `<i>` appears in the template `$str`

```
@outputArray  = map { my $i=$str; $i =~ s/\<i\>/$_/; $i } @arr
```

You need to copy `$str` to a temporary because replace works in-place. If you used `$str` directly then its value would be changed the first time.

Comment: The `r` flag on your regex will let you do this more cleanly.

Comment: Just using `map{ $str=~s/<i>/$_/r }` works fine. No need for the temp variable or to escape the `<` and `>`.